# Is there a way to specify android:layout_height dynamically during onCreate?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I would like to set

> android:layout_height="**wrap_content**"

to some pixels(**int**) during my application start. This is a textView and the reason behind this is that i want the height of the textView dynamic based on some inputs from my end which will be computed when the onCreate method is called.

Is this possible? if yes any example would be great.

Forgot to add my textView xml looks like this

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/sometext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fadingEdge="vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/dropshadow"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:text="Getting data on your slow n/w..."
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
               />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just edit the layout params of the view.

```
TextView v = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sometext);
LayoutParams lp = v.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = 50;
v.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The view will be 50px high in this example.

Note that it's generally not recommended to use pixel dimensions for layouts due to the many device specs out there. Rather use dp *(density independent pixels)* instead. You can calculate pixel dimensions from dp values in the following way *(50dp to px here)*:

```
float dp = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 50,
                                     getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Comment: Thanks alextsc. But my problem is even doing this its not reflecting. My code is this.     ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = sometext.getLayoutParams();
  lp.height = 10;
  sometext.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: Do you use `findViewById()` to get a reference to the textview as used in this sample? Or do you create a new view from code *(which might just not be added to the layout)*? Also test if you got the correct LayoutParams imported, there are quite a few of them in the framework. The right one is `ViewGroup.LayoutParams` here.

Comment: Hi alextsc, it worked. looks like apk file was cached. Even deleting several things from xml it was still working fine :| so deleted the .apk and once created  again i can see the change. Thanks